Pytesseract OCR not detecting numbers with less than 3 digits
I have a python script that captures a segment of the screen and reads what the text value of it is and converts the text to only numerical characters returns it. My problem is that pytesseract only reads numbers that have digits that are 3 or greater and never 2 or lower.
I captured a small segment of my screen and had pytesseract read and extract text from it, but this only works when there are 3 or more digits.
Sample Image:Captured segment of my screen
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
import time
import pydirectinput
import pygetwindow as gw

from mss import mss
import re

def filter_numbers(text):
    filtered_text = re.sub(r'\D', '', text)
    return filtered_text

topMost = 1005
Pheight = 45
Pwidth = 55
leftMost = 170

useButtonCoordinateX, useButtonCoordinateY  = 403, 726

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'


def capture_screen_and_read_text():
   
    region = {'top': topMost, 'left': leftMost, 'width': Pwidth, 'height': Pheight}
    time.sleep(2)
    with mss() as sct:
        screen = sct.grab(region)

        img = np.array(screen)

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        _, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

        resized_img = cv2.resize(thresh, None, fx=2, fy=2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
        cv2.imshow('Screen Capture', resized_img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(resized_img)
        return text

capture_screen_and_read_text()


Please read tesseract documentation (there is section how to improve OCR result) and/or search SO.
